# WCF FaultException<ApplicationException> fails if an inner exception is specified for the ApplicationException

Tags: c#, wcf, faultexception

I have been debugging an issue with my newly minted WCF services Fault contract and finally found out what was breaking it.

I defined the service like so:

```
[ServiceContract]

public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ApplicationException))]
    string GetData();
}
```

in my service I was handling exception in the service like so:

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        try
        {
           // do stuff
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ApplicationException ae = new ApplicationException("oh dear!", e );
            throw new FaultException<ApplicationException>( ae, 
                                                 new FaultReason(ae.Message));
        }
    }
```

However, the client would never receive the fault exception, instead it would get an exception which said:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ... This could
>   be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
>   This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server ( possibly due to the service shutting down).See server logs
>   for more details

If I changed my code on the service like so (ie: do NOT set the inner exception when constructing the ApplicationException) it works as expected.

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        try
        {
           // do stuff
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ApplicationException ae = new ApplicationException("oh dear!");
            throw new FaultException<ApplicationException>( ae, 
                                                 new FaultReason(ae.Message));
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this might fail if the inner exception is set? I could not see it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `ApplicationException` is sent to the client via `FaultException<T>` without the `InnerException`, then it is sent only as a `string`. However, when the `InnerException` is set, then the `ApplicationException` itself is sent.

The `Exception` type is serializable in .NET (it is often incorrectly cited as not being serializable), however, frequently the contents of the [`Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property are not serializable. This will cause a serialization issue which is what I believe you are experiencing.

There are a few workarounds to this issue: You can set the `Data` property to `null` by using reflection or you can create your own class.

Comment: thanks, in the end I just used the Message property of my application exception, and included the relevant information that would have been in the inner exception. Even so, I'm left wondering what is the point of FaultException<ApplicationException>, as if I do not specify an additional FaultMessage when raising it on the server side then the client doesn't even see the contents of ApplicationException.Message !!!